# How to redirect user to another page during a maintenance activity in JIRA

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-plugin

I'm new to Jira plugins development, could anyone help me out with how to redirect all "non-admin" personnel to another page during a maintenance activity.

I would also want to push some data values from a gui to a some code that would determine when the maintenance activity has started.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should split this into two questions: 1) how to redirect the non-admin members, and 2) how to get data on maintenance from JIRA.

Comment: Actually all i want to do is to redirect non-admin personnel to another page while admin person still accessing the server/website.